# How to stop "top many rerenders" when checking if database information is pulled?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, database, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I'm trying to cause a delay between the database data being pulled and the calculation for BMI occurring but the if statement check is causing "too many rerenders" issue. how do I get around the this?

```
function Main_page(props) {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [healthData, healthDataSet] = useState(null)
    const [BMI, BMIset] = useState(null)
    const [BMR, BMRset] = useState(null) 


    useEffect(() => {

        const user = Authentication.auth().currentUser;
        {
            user !== null &&
                Authentication.firestore().collection('Health_data')
                    .doc(user.uid)
                    .get()
                    .then(doc => {
                        healthDataSet(doc.data())
                        setLoading(false)
                    }).catch(function (error) {
                        console.error("Error reading health", error);
                    });
        }
        return () => {
            document.body.style.overflow = 'unset';
        }

    }, []);

    if (!loading) {
        BMIset(healthData.weight/(healthData.height^2))
    }
```

Here is a snippet of my code the calculation should only be made once loading is set to false. what's the fix here? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`useEffect` + [its second parameter should do the trick](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects).

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(!loading && healthData !== null) 
        BMIset(healthData.weight/(healthData.height^2))
}, [loading, healthData]);
```

This way:

- `loading`'s default state is `true`
- `healthData`'s default state is `null`

You query firestore and when it returns a successful response you set:

- `loading` to `false`
- `healthData` to document returned by firestore

The new `useEffect` *will skip* effect if `loading` and `healthData` are not changed. Then you calculate set BMI when `loading` is `false` & `healthData` is not empty.

Comment: Brilliant thank you I'll give that a try now an let you know how I get on

Comment: Just to be clear I add a completely separate useEffect? also was is the if statement doing if nothing is contained in it?

Comment: @lukeet Yes, separate `useEffect()` and the `if` statement is not empty. You can omit braces `{}` if there's only one statement per condition. You can read more at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else